# Class path resource [application-test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

i have this annotations in my test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration 
@ActiveProfiles ("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
```

And this files in my project:

[image]

But when i try to launch tests i receive this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Already i refresh the project, close eclipse and launch maven clean, maven update, maven install... but nothing. Someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Check your build path if it is added in your classpath

Comment: Seems ok, do you run via the IDE? I would try using Maven from the terminal

Comment: That file is already loaded by Spring Boot (due to the `@ActiveProfiles ("test")`), so I suggest to ditch the `@TestPropertySource`. I would also suggest to go with properties OR yaml don't start to mix them.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was:

1. Intellij Idea - File - Project Structure - Modules - src - test - java - resources - mark resources as "Test Resources".
2. `@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties");`

[Open this image. It will help you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJD8m.jpg)

3. refresh gradle/maven dependencies

Answer (score 2):

in eclipse, Go to build path->source tab , remove Excluded "**" from src/test/resource

Answer (score 1):

If the IDE is Some times the resource root folders doesnt get updated.
Just delete the .idea folder and re-import the project again. That should work

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Maven structured must follow.

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java
- src/test/resources

If you generated your project through command prompt kindly verify above folder structure.

---

In case you want without IDE use below plugin in your POM.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-test-resource</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>path/to/additional/test/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/folder-to-exclude/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution> 
  </executions>
</plugin>
```